# javascript extending existing prototype pattern to support more options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to see how basic prototype patterns work. I am trying to see how can I extend existing functionality of a widget. Think of it as a plugin extension system

**Requirement:**

1. file `widgets.calculator.js` has one `option={ text: ''}`
2. in `main.js` I can now call `new window.widgets.calculator({ text: 'Root Element' });`
3. in another file `widgets.calculator-extension.js` i want to extend functionality of existing `widgets.calculator.js` to support one more option and perhaps few other functions
4. so that now in `main.js` I should be able to use other option as well like
   `new window.widgets.calculator({
   text: 'Root Element',
   input: 'form input'
   });`

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/7scxed7j/

**CODE:**

```
// file widgets.calculator.js
(function (widgets, $, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  widgets.calculator = function (options) {
    this.options = $.extend(true, {
      text: 'some text'
    }, options);
    //
    this.ele = $('<div/>').html(this.options.text).addClass('ui-calculator').appendTo('body');
    //
  };
  widgets.calculator.prototype = {
    getRootElement: function () {
      return this.ele;
    }
  };
}(window.widgets = window.widgets || {}, jQuery));
//
//
//main.js
var widget = new window.widgets.calculator({
  text: 'Root Element'
});
console.log(widget.getRootElement());
//

/*
// widgets.calculator-extension.js
// how to extend existing widgets.calculator with more options
// 
//main.js
var widget = new window.widgets.calculator({
  text: 'Root Element',
  input: 'form input'
});
console.log(widget.getInput());
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// file widgets.calculator.js
(function (widgets, $, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  widgets.calculator = function (options) {
    this.options = $.extend(true, {
      text: 'some text'
    }, options);
    //
    this.ele = $('<div/>').html(this.options.text).addClass('ui-calculator').appendTo('body');
    //
  };
  widgets.calculator.prototype = {
    getRootElement: function () {
      return this.ele;
    }
  };
}(window.widgets = window.widgets || {}, jQuery));
//
// widgets.calculator-extension.js
(function (widgets, $, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  var extension = Object.create(widgets.calculator);
  console.log(extension);
  //cannot use extension.options because extensions is not an instance
  //if (extension.options.input) {
  //  extension.eleInput = $('<input/>').addClass('ui-input').appendTo(extension.ele);
 // }
  extension.getInput = function () {
    return this.ele;
  };
  widgets.calculator.prototype = extension;
  widgets.calculator.constructor = widgets.calculator;

}(window.widgets = window.widgets || {}, jQuery));
// how to extend existing widgets.calculator with more options
//
//main.js
var widget = new window.widgets.calculator({
  text: 'Root Element',
  input: 'dd'
});
console.log(widget.getInput());
//
```

Comment: I tried but does not seem to work. Can u please check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/7scxed7j/3/

Comment: if i cant use ```if (extension.options.input) {``` then i still have problem